# How to get post time stamp on Social Engine

Tags: socialengine

Hi I am trying to get a user up time stamp in the format of "Last Update: ten minutes ago" or "Last Update: 1 hour ago" or "Last Update: yesterday" or "Last Update: three days ago" etc.

I want to be able to echo out the time stamp. 
please find what i already have below:

```
$currentUserID=Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()->getIdentity();
$sSqlInviter="select creation_date  from engine4_core_status where resource_id=".$currentUserID;
$dbInviterSqli=Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$stmtInviter=$dbInviterSqli->query($sSqlInviter);
$rowInviter=$stmtInviter->fetch();
$post_time_count=$rowInviter['creation_date'];
echo $this->timestamp($post_time_count);
```

but it starts counting from when i refresh the page.

Thanks in advance

I have been able to resolve this too..

```
$sSqlInviter="select creation_date  from engine4_core_status where resource_id=".$currentUserID." order by creation_date desc limit 1";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got the time from your db, but the problem is how to use it right considering the timezone. You can try to use parts of this code:

```
$oldTz = date_default_timezone_get();               // get old timezone
date_default_timezone_set($viewer->timezone);       // temporarily set user's timezone as default
$start = strtotime($starttime);                     // do something you need
date_default_timezone_set($oldTz);                  // set default timezone back for the rest part of controller
$starttime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);           // use existing data
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Kirk Hammett, I am a baby developer here and just trying to create something that works.. I know I haven't done it rightly as will be setting multiple connection to the database at the end. What i have is working but just need help to simplify it.

like:

`$currentUserID=Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()->getIdentity()->getLastPostTime();`    Just looking for a simple way to get this done rather than connecting to the db as this is wearing me out. THANKS

Comment: No problem :) 
You can use API of any module you like. For example, Engine_Api::_()->user()->yourMethod(); is yourMethod() placed into User/Api/Core.php. Inside yourMethod() you can prepare and return anything you need.

Comment: Hello Kirk Hammett, My Default Timezone in socialengine by admin and my pc is set to UTC+6 DHaka but $viewer->timezone shows US/Pacific.

Comment: @Tanvir user can select his timezone on signup, so for him it is set as US/Pacific... it depends on your signup settings I think

Comment: Thank u bro,But I m logged in as admin user.What does the admin locale setting Timezone do then? How do I get my PC's time,not server time.I m spending whole day finding this? pls help

Comment: Yes bro, I changed my profile setting's timezone to my timezone.But $this->locale()->toDateTime($this->date) returns 1 hour late than my current time. Why is it that?